# Error in calling json api for cocktailDB in iOS swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am trying to call a json api in swift. I am using the CocktailDB, and swift for iOS. I am getting an error saying "Thread 3: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Anyone know why the data is not being pulled and is nil when decoding?

Here is the code:

```
class Drinks {
    //URL Links
    let shotURL = "www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Shot"
    
    //Response Structure
    struct shotResponse: Codable {
        var drinks: [MyShotDrink]
    }
    
    //Drink Structure
    struct MyShotDrink: Codable {
        var strDrink = ""
        var strDrinkThumb = ""
        var idDrink = ""
        
    }
    
    
    var shotArray: [MyShotDrink] = []
    
    func getData(completed: @escaping ()->()){
        
        //Create a URL
        guard let url = URL(string: shotURL) else {
            print("ERROR: Could not create a URL")
            completed()
            return
            
        }
        
        //Create a session
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        //Get data
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            //Handle data
            do {
                let returned = try JSONDecoder().decode(shotResponse.self, from: data!)
                self.shotArray = returned.drinks
            } catch {
                print("JSON ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            completed()
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code crashes because you proceed after the `URLSession` error. You should insert a `return` statement after printing the error.

The error says

> unsupported URL

and looking at the URL reveals the problem. Pure `www` URLs are invalid, an URL needs a scheme (`http`) and modern URLs even use `https`

```
let shotURL = "https://thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Shot"
```